# Where can I find the template used in risk.net associated journals?

Tags: templates, journal

Where can I find the template used in those journals associated with risk.net, e.g. 
Journal of Operational Risk
Journal of Credit Risk
Journal of Risk 
etc. ?

While the site says that there is no general template for the articles, it is obvious that most (all?) articles have used the same template. An example can be found here:

http://www.eurekafinancial.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Systemic-operational-risk1.pdf

thx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The PDF says it is "TeX output"; if you're not able to find a template, it probably means that they hand the manuscripts to some company that transform them in TeX form.

Answer (score 1):

From the [risk journal submission guidelines](http://www.risk.net/static/risk-journals-submission-guidelines):
"Risk Journals does not have a standard template for submissions - we just ask that you ensure your paper is written clearly and follows the below guidelines." The template they might have will be applied post-submission.